# How to send/receive videotestsrc images encoded as JPEG using RTP with GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I want to send/receive videotestsrc images encoded as JPEG using RTP with GStreamer.
I tried the following commands. It can be sent and received test image.
But, received image is not correct. It is broken. It seems image is dark and misaligned.
How to send and receive images normally?

- send command

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

- receive command

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, encoding-name=JPEG, framerate=30/1, payload=26, clock-rate=90000 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

### result

[image]

### environment

- windows 10
- gstreamer 1.18.3

Comment: Strange it works for me on Linux, gst 1.16.2.
Have you tried different videosink just for test?
Does it pick YUY2 on receiving end correctly (check logs)?

Comment: you could just use different video format.. as I have randomly found out, rtp jpeg payloader has problems with some formats. Check this: http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/ximagesrc-to-jpegenc-td4669619.html
So you could use `format=I420` just for test if it helps.

Comment: I have tried it, but result was no different. It's broken as well.  
`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=I420 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`

Comment: what happens if you use videosink instead of udpsink - is it correct there?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=I420 ! autovideosink`

Comment: then it means its messed up after the transmission I guess. well then go ahead and try more things.. you can add various caps filters before the receivers autovideosink, use different videosink then DirectX one, try to inspect what is transmitted with wireshark, submit a bug, ask on IRC #gstreamer at freenode, check for existings bugs .. all depending on how badly you want to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@ken
This works great under linux (ubuntu 20.04). I suppose there's something about Windows and/or direct 3d. It looks like this

[image]

so seems good.